how to calculate the efficiency of hybrid drones?
I'm looking at this new kind of drones:
https://www.xer-tech.com/drones/x8/
And I'm trying to calculate the overall efficiency of the powertrain.
The numbers I'm getting don't really match up to the specs I'm seeing.
How would you go about calculating the efficiency of the powertrain?
Thanks,
